# Alternate query for cross apply in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CREATEDBY, PITCHES, [COUNT], REVENUE, ORD 
FROM 
    @TEMPMAILER
CROSS APPLY  
    (VALUES ('Total Active', CNTACTIVE, TOTALREVACT, 0),
            ('In Suspect', CNTSUSPECT, TOTALREVS, 1),
            ('In Prospect', CNTPROSPECT, TOTALREVP, 2),
            ('In Approach', CNTAPPROACH, TOTALREVA, 3),
            ('In Negotiation', CNTNEGO, TOTALREVN, 4),
            ('In Closure', CNTCLOSURE, TOTALREVC, 5),
            ('In Order', CNTORDER, TOTALREVO, 6)) V (PITCHES,[COUNT], REVENUE, ORD)
```

I want data to come in 2nd form as in the image without using cross apply.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: No image added. But better would be just a simple text layout added to the question like the query

Comment: will keep the image thing in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't give any reason for wanting to avoid `CROSS APPLY`.

I'm assuming this is because your current query doesn't work in 2005 and you have come to the incorrect conclusion that this is the fault of the `APPLY`. The reason your query doesn't work in 2005 is beacuse of the `VALUES` not the `APPLY`.

This will work in 2005.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CREATEDBY,
                PITCHES,
                [COUNT],
                REVENUE,
                ORD
FROM   @TEMPMAILER
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 'Total Active',CNTACTIVE,TOTALREVACT,0 UNION ALL
                SELECT 'In Suspect',CNTSUSPECT,TOTALREVS,1 UNION ALL
                SELECT 'In Prospect',CNTPROSPECT,TOTALREVP,2 UNION ALL
                SELECT 'In Approach',CNTAPPROACH,TOTALREVA,3 UNION ALL
                SELECT 'In Negotiation',CNTNEGO,TOTALREVN,4 UNION ALL
                SELECT 'In Closure',CNTCLOSURE,TOTALREVC,5 UNION ALL
                SELECT 'In Order',CNTORDER,TOTALREVO,6               
                )V(PITCHES,[COUNT],REVENUE,ORD)
```

Comment: hi..thanks for the answer...although i want to know the reason why values doesnt work in 2005?

Comment: @SUPERGIRL - [`Table Value Constructor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd776382.aspx) syntax wasn't added to the product until SQL Server 2008.